# Unable to install Dataplicity on Raspbian: port 443 error

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I've previously used [Dataplicity](https://www.dataplicity.com) without issues. Recently I reformatted my SD card with a fresh Raspbian OS and would like to install Dataplicity again.

However, when I use the curl script provided on the Dataplicity website to install the software I get the following error:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.dataplicity.com port 443: Network is unreachable
```

I'm unsure why this is occurring, as the Pi has internet connection and there appears to be no issues with the Dataplicity site otherwise. Has anyone experienced this issue and found a solution?

Comment: Try https://tunnelin.com service - it does not rely on WebSocket communication like Dataplicity does, instead, it creates secure tunnels to your devices, making you able to expose your network services like ssh, vnc, https, proxy, etc. As a result, the security of Tunnel In is much higher! As well as it provides an easily configurable firewall to limit connections by time, IP address, and connection rate (security against brute force attacks).

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to run 'curl https://www.dataplicity.com/' on your Pi without error?  If not, it could be either a network connection issue, or something like a proxy server interfering with your ability to reach the dataplicity.com site from your device.
Best,
Elliot.

Comment: No, the curl command brings up that response quoted above. I'm not behind a proxy and am able to connect to the dataplicity website on my other devices

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Try running the following command:

```
echo ipv4 >> ~/.curlrc
```